# Will items in Amazon Drive's "Deleted" folder ever be automatically removed?

Tags: amazon-cloud-drive

Amazon Drive provides "unlimited" storage for files and folders. When files and folders are *deleted*, they are *moved* to the special "Deleted" folder where they can be either restored or permanently deleted (just like in Windows).

Will items stored in the special "Deleted" folder ever be removed automatically?

Do any of these factors matter? :

- file/folder size
- item type (file or folder)
- nested level (depth of folder path)
- shared status (Deleted items can still be shared, though the shared link will not show the deleted item until it has been undeleted. See [share link](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/gVoWll7dfA7F7p4CVYLkmmQ10ruCIQi1upVVtLAo6kd?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy) of two items: "folder-1" and "file-1". See [share link](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/5qnLDYKMgbgoRTUF3bQjc83cMZCmhjOwgwg8g6PFRMv?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy) of 4 items: "folder-1", "file-1", "folder-2", "file-2". Note that "folder-1" and "file-1" are currently in the "Deleted" folder.)

Is there any information regarding this issue?

Can we count on items in "Deleted" to be still recoverable after more than a few months/years?